# How does sender find ip address of the destination (in a WAN)?

Tags: networking

We need the destination ip and Mac address to send data right? So if I want to send some data to another host on a completely different network, how does the device find it's ip address? (Like in case of websites, it uses dns)

Comment: Default gateway and by ARP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a computer is connected to an IPv4* over Ethernet network a number of things need to be configured. This configuration may be performed manually but nowadays it is more commonly done using DHCP.

- IP address
- Subnet mask
- Default gateway
- DNS server(s)

The IP address, subnet mask and default gateway settings are used to establish the default state of the routing table.

The configuration of the network connection is used in conjunction with information configured or hard coded in the application to find the destination, there will often be multiple layers of lookup, for example.

- Sometimes, an application specific lookup service may be used to determine the actual destination. This application specific lookup service will often have special functionality to work around firewalls and network address translators. It may also have fallback mechanisms to route data via the application operators service if a direct connection cannot be established.
- DNS is likely to be used either to find the IP address for the application specific lookup service or to find the destination directly.
- The routing table is used both to determine what interface a packet should be sent from, and to determine what the "next hop IP address" for that packet will be.
- ARP is used to translate "next hop IP addresses" to mac addresses.

* IPv6 handles things a bit differently, but the basic ideas are quite similar.

Answer (score 2):

For a completely different network, you don't need the MAC of the destination, only the MAC of your default gateway.

Presumably, you know who you are sending data to (otherwise, why are you sending it?).  If you have a hostname, you can use DNS to resolve the name to IP.

If you don't have a hostname, or there isn't DNS available, then you will need to know the IP address of the destination.